# Trim Characters From sqlite3

Tags: sql, function, sqlite, trim

I have an sqlite3 database that I imported from CSV, but the CSV quoted all data. now, the data is all wrapped with quotes in the database, and I’d like to remove them. So, my data looks like this:

```
"90210","CA"
```

Is there a quick-and-dirty sqlite3 command I can run to trim those quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.
This function is called `trim`.
Look for more info in official documentation http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 3):

There is the [trim](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function:

```
UPDATE thetable SET value = trim(value, "\"");
```